# Path of the requiring script inside the required script

Tags: node.js, path, require

I have two scripts: the first requiring the second.

1st script main.js:

```
...
var a = require(second);
...
```

2d. script second.js

```
path = path/of/the/main/script
```

I want to get access to the path of the first script within the second script without passing it as argument. Is it a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.parent.filename` holds the file name of the calling script. See [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent) for more information.